# skel.js dynamically create row from data in database

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive web app using skel.js and, amongst other things, it has to display a bunch of data from a mysql database in little boxes arranged in groups of 3 per row. The problem i'm facing is how do i arrange the data from the mysql database so that for every 3 records it automatically creates a row with 3 boxes and so on.

Right now i'm using jQuery to do this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      var divs = $("div#boxes");
      for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
      divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
  }
});
```

Yet, this way, when the page loads, all the boxes are glued together. Half a second later, give or take, the final layout is working as intended. I want to remove that ugly glued box effect from the equation.

I've thought about "lazy loading" the records, in groups of 3 and building the html markup "on the fly" but that will have a much rather strong impact on performance, imo. What do you think?

Can you help me?

PS. The markup for each row is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="12u">
        <section>
            <div class="4u" id="boxes">
                <section class="box">
                    <!-- mySQL data -->
                </section>
                <section class="box">
                    <!-- mySQL data -->
                </section>
                <section class="box">
                    <!-- mySQL data -->
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```